# Install ubuntu 12.04 in vmware runing on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: vmware

So, my question is: I instaled vmware 8 on windows 7, 64 bit and I tried to install ubuntu 12.04 in vmware as a guest OS. Installation was normal, but when ubuntu started to load I can see a massage "Installing wmvare tools, please wait ... and that's it.
Could anyone help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740243/ubuntu-intallation-is-stuck-at-vmware-tools-installation
Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with Worksattion 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried the suggested solutions, however they did not work.

What worked for me was Creating the VM first by choosing the option "I will install the OS later"

then mount the iso on the CDROM through the settings window and boot it up.

Worked 1st time.

also once its finished copying the files disconnect the cd rom at reboot

Sources : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740243/ubuntu-intallation-is-stuck-at-vmware-tools-installation

[Stuck at 'VMware easy install'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126229/12-04-stuck-at-vmware-easy-install)