# Problem in VMware Installation(12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, vmware, community

I had problem when installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS on vmware, after install and require a restart when booting directly appear display terminal and not unity environment :(

there that know ?

```
*********************************************
*********************************************
VMware Easy Install

>PLEASE WAIT! VMware Tools is currently being 
installed on your system. Depending on the 
version of Ubuntu you are installing, you may
log in below and use the system during the 
installation. Otherwise, please wait for the
graphical environment to launch. Thank you

*********************************************
*********************************************

ubuntu login:
```

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the desktop and not the server version of Ubuntu? Do you get a normal console to log in (TTY) or a error console?

Comment: i think pabi is right @user294578

Comment: yes friend, sure i have installation ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop not server -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that you installed ubuntu-desktop, then login to the system 
then type startx, if desktop is installed then it'll load the unity or else you have to install it by
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: huaaaaaaaaaa :D  thanks friend solved arigatou :D

Answer (score 1):

It says it right there in the Text you posted.
The VMWare tools are currently getting installed. Just wait till it is finished, then the Desktop will start.

It may be that Vmware Tools requires some dependencies that are not installed from your installation, I've had this happen before. Try installing the Open VM Tools instead with:
`sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`

Otherwise try this solution:
[Stuck at 'VMware easy install'](https://askubuntu.com/a/127107/294490)